# Необходима ли запятая перед союзом "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

***Туфли купила на один размер меньше, они адски жали () и пришлось их отдать.***

Такое ощущение, что здесь не надо ставить запятую перед **"и"**:  вроде здесь нет для этого никаких причин (общего члена предложения и т. д). Здесь все очевидно или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Вы перепутали: при "общем члене и т.д." как раз НЕ ставится запятая между основами, а здесь общего члена нет, поэтому и ставится.

Comment: Нет-нет, я как раз пишу, что нет оснований, чтобы ее не ставить, коряво сформулировала. Сама не знаю, почему меня сбило с толку это предложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Туфли **купила** на один размер меньше, (2) **они** адски **жали**, и (3) пришлось их **отдать.**

Запятая нужна, три предикативные основы, бессоюзная и союзная связь.

Предложения 1 и 3 односоставные  (определенно-личное и безличное).

Предложения 2 и 3 более тесно связаны по смыслу и интонационно, но запятые ставятся по грамматическим правилам.